# ¿Cómo soluciono un error con Microsoft.Bot.Connector "Error de validación del nombre seguro

Tags: .net-core

Realicé la actualización de Microsoft.Bot.Builder 3.9.0 a Microsoft.Bot.Builder 3.11.0, restauré packages Nuget y compile mi proyecto y todo salió bien. Pero al correr mi aplicación muestra un error:

> FileLoadException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'Microsoft.Bot.Connector, Version=3.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ni una de sus dependencias. Error de validación del nombre seguro. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x8013141A)

¿Qué esta generando este error? Probé en otra máquina y en ésta si funcionó correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías decirnos cuáles son las versiones de .net Core de ambas máquinas por favor?

Comment: [Strong Name Validation Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36424942/4092887) o busca `0x8013141A` en Google.

Comment: Si claro la versión de .net Core en ambas maquinas es 2.0.0. Windows 10